# Remove active class from previous div on selecting new div

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have set active class to div on selecting the div but now I want to remove previous active class whenever I select a new div.

But here I am not getting how to remove active class from previous selected div.

Source of code for generating tree structure : http://jsfiddle.net/brendanowen/uXbn6/8/

**Template:**

```
<table ng-repeat="data in tree track by $index">
    <tbody>
        <div ng-click="setDivActive(data)" ng-class="{'active': data.selected}"></div>  //This div will be selected
     </tbody>
  </table>

<script type="text/ng-template"  id="tree_item_renderer.html">
 <button ng-click="add(data)">Add node</button>
 <table ng-repeat="data in data.nodes" id="tree_item_renderer.html">
    <tbody>
        <div ng-click="setDivActive(data)" ng-class="{'active': data.selected}"></div>  //This div will be selected
    </tbody>
 </table>
</script>
```

**Controller:**

```
 $scope.tree = [{name: "Node", nodes: [],selected:false}];
 $scope.addNode = function (data) {
        var post = data.nodes.length + 1;
        var newName = data.name + '-' + post;
        data.nodes.push({ name: newName, nodes: [],selected:false });
    };

$scope.setDivActive= function (data) {
        data.selected = true;
    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you set the new item as the selected one, iterate over the entire collection and set all of them to 'not selected':

```
function clearSelected(items) {
    items.forEach(function(item) {
        item.selected = false;
        if (item.nodes) {
            clearSelected(item.nodes);
        }
    });
}

$scope.setDivActive= function (data) {
    clearSelected($scope.tree);
    data.selected = true;
};
```

Comment: I don't really understand how your nested structure is supposed to work, but you need to make a recursive function then

Comment: Updated my answer to be recursive for nested constructs, you might need to tweak it since I'm not really sure how your tree structure is supposed to look

Comment: Yeah now it is working fine.Thank you so much for your kind efforts towards helping me and please keep helping like this :)